# BroadCast receiver executing multiple times

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a problem where my `BroadcastReceiver` is getting registered several times.

My Application has a `CountDownTimer` in the `Application` object. The reason why it is in this class is because once it has been started, the user should be able to move to other Activities while it is counting down.

Once the `CountDownTimer` has counted down, i then launch a `LocalBroadcast` which a certain `Activity` is registered to receive.

Everything works fine apart from the `onReceive` is called multiples times. If for example the user starts the `CountDownTimer` in Activity1, then moves to  Activity2 then back moves back to Activity1, the `onReceive` is called twice.

The `launchMode` of the Activity is set to `SingleInstance` and `noHistory` is set to `true`. This is my attempt to only have one instance of the registering Activity and hopefully one receiver.

This is my `CountDownTimer` in the `Application` Object:

```
public static void startLoneworkerCountDownTimer(int duration){
     long durationInMillis = duration * 60 * 1000;
     cdt = null;
     cdt = new CountDownTimer(durationInMillis, 1000) {
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
              setLoneWorkerCountDownTimerRunning(true);
              int secs = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
              int mins = secs / 60;
              secs = secs % 60;
              // int milliseconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished % 1000);
              loneWorkerTimerValue = mins + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs);

              //tvCountDown.setText(timerValue);
         }

         public void onFinish() {
              setLoneWorkerCountDownTimerRunning(false);
              loneWorkerTimerValue = "0:00";
              Log.e(TAG, "LoneWorker Timer is done.");
              LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(new LoneworkerCountdownFinishedIntent());
          }
     }.start();
}
```

This is how i initialize, register and unregister my receiver:

```
public void unRegisterCountDownFinishedReceiver(){         
     try {
         unregisterReceiver(countDownFinishedreceiver);
     } catch (Exception e) {}
}//end of unRegisterCountDownFinishedReceiver


public void initializeCountDownFinishedReceiver(){
    if(countDownFinishedreceiver == null){
        countDownFinishedreceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.e(TAG, "inside onReceive in countDownFinishedreceiver");
                //do something
            }//end of onReceive
        };
    }
}//end of registerCountDownReceiver()

public void registerCountDownFinishedReceiver(){
    Log.e(TAG, "about to register countDownFinishedreceiver!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!***********!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
        .registerReceiver(countDownFinishedreceiver,new IntentFilter(LoneworkerCountdownFinishedIntent.ACTION_COUNTDOWN_FINISHED));
}
```

This is my intent for the `LocalBroadcast`:

```
import android.content.Intent;

public class LoneworkerCountdownFinishedIntent extends Intent {
    public static final String ACTION_COUNTDOWN_FINISHED = "com.xxxxx.countdownfinished";

    public LoneworkerCountdownFinishedIntent() {
        super(ACTION_COUNTDOWN_FINISHED);
    }
}
```

In `onCreate` i call the following only when the `CountDownTimer` is running in the `Application` class:

```
initializeCountDownFinishedReceiver();
        registerCountDownFinishedReceiver();
```

.

My question is how can i ensure that there is only on Receiver registered at any one time?

I want the user to be able to launch the Activity as manytimes as they want while the `CountDownTimer` is running but only have one `onReceive` run.

Comment: why coundowntimer is not in service?

Comment: @sector11 I thought the best way for it to run independant of any Activity would be in Application class. Could you expand on how you would do it please?